# Cubesat 6U and 12U maximum weight

Tags: launch, artificial-satellite, cubesat

What is the maximum weight for 6U and 12U cubesat in kg.? 
Please, give links/references.

In this [link](http://www.planetarysystemscorp.com/web/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2002367D-Payload-Spec-for-3U-6U-12U-27U.pdf) it's stated that, 6U is 12kg, 12U is 24kg. But 1U is 1.33 kg, how is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different standards. The original standard is 1 kg/ unit, but there are other options today. CalPoly, which launches the highest number of cubesats today, sets the [standard](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5418c831e4b0fa4ecac1bacd/t/56e9b62337013b6c063a655a/1458157095454/cds_rev13_final2.pdf) at 1.33 kg/ unit. If you have a cubesat launched by someone else, they might allow even more mass. NASA [states](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/cubesat_launch_initiative_announcement_2017.pdf) that simply it depends on the dispenser, which is true.